# Products don't show in categories, only in search

Tags: frontend, products

I am not programmer, but web designer, once I made magento e-store with success.

Now I have problem with products display. They are not visible in Categories, but if I search for SKU or product name, they display, but if I click on it, there is empty page opening

> HTTP ERROR 500

I have searched for solutions without success, and of course, all main settings are correct (visible, in stock, amount, correct category etc.)
I use magento 1.9 and my site is with 3 languages (works ok)

Please help!

Comment: Check your log file and post the error.

Comment: Change your Visibility as `Catalog, Search`

Comment: did you get your answer??

Comment: No I didn't get answer what helps

Comment: Error_log file says:
[27-Sep-2017 14:27:16 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object in /home/ingridiz/mdbaltic.ingridizains.lv/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 819

Comment: I don;t know what it's mean. In this file, in line 819 is:    $this->getParentBlock()->addToChildGroup($groupName, $this);

Answer (score 2):

Login your `admin panel` and goto `Catalog->Manage Products` select your products.

In `General` change your product's Visibility as `Catalog, Search`.

I hope it will work.

Comment: Visibility is Catalog,Search from beginning

Answer (score 0):

There should be issue of your theme!

I mean if you have used any theme, then there is possibility that the product page code is not compatible with your Magento current version?

So, please check this first!

Best of Luck...

Comment: I use Dresscode theme:Dresscode is premium responsive magento theme which can be used according to your needs and requirements. It includes a lot of custom features. Fully responsive, customizable, based on Sceleton CSS Framework. Compatible with magento 1.9.x, 1.8.x, 1.7.x, 1.6.x

Answer (score 0):

This may help!

Navigate to Admin Panel `Catalog -> Manage Categories` (Select the category) and navigate to Display Settings tab. Look for the option **Display Mode** this should be set to `Product only` or `static Block with Products`

Error Code 500 shows server error, You should check for custom redirects. that may help you.

Comment: Display mode is Product only

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me once when I mistakenly set the product to a root category , i.e the default category or the category which contains all other categories.
So, please check if you have got the same case.

Comment: No my products are connected with subcategories